# DataGridView DateTimePicker Column - add Long Format support (Date and the Time)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I'm trying to make gridview Datetimepicker column and i succeeded,
but i have a little problem that when the user edit the date in the gridview
the date appear in short "11/9/16" but what i want is the date and the time together"11/9/16 2:34:45 AM"

This is the code I use:

CalendarColumn:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class CalendarColumn
Inherits DataGridViewColumn

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New CalendarCell())
End Sub

Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
    Get
        Return MyBase.CellTemplate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

        ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
        If (value IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
            Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(CalendarCell)) _
            Then
            Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell")
        End If
        MyBase.CellTemplate = value

    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

CalendarCell:

```
Public Class CalendarCell
Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Public Sub New()
    ' Use the short date format.
    'Me.Style.Format = "d"
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
    ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, _
    ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)

    ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
    MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, _
        dataGridViewCellStyle)

    Dim ctl As CalendarEditingControl = _
        CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, CalendarEditingControl)

    ' Use the default row value when Value property is null.
    If (Me.Value Is Nothing) Then
        ctl.Value = CType(Me.DefaultNewRowValue, DateTime)
    Else
        ctl.Value = CType(Me.Value, DateTime)
    End If
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
    Get
        ' Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
        Return GetType(CalendarEditingControl)
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType() As Type
    Get
        ' Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
        Return GetType(DateTime)
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue() As Object
    Get
        ' Use the current date and time as the default value.
        Return DateTime.Now
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

CalendarEditingControl:

```
Class CalendarEditingControl
Inherits DateTimePicker
Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
Private rowIndexNum As Integer

Public Sub New()
     Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long
    'Me.CustomFormat = "'Today is:' hh:mm:ss dddd MMMM dd, yyyy"
End Sub

Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue

    Get
        Return Me.Value.ToShortDateString()
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        Try
            ' This will throw an exception of the string is 
            ' null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
            Me.Value = DateTime.Parse(CStr(value))
        Catch
            ' In the case of an exception, just use the default
            ' value so we're not left with a null value.
            Me.Value = DateTime.Now
        End Try
    End Set

End Property

Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(ByVal context _
    As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue

    Return Me.Value.ToShortDateString()

End Function

Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As _
    DataGridViewCellStyle) _
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl

    Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
    Me.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
    Me.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor

End Sub
```

And this code for add column :

```
Dim col As New CalendarColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Date time"}
DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, col)
```

[source Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)

How can I make it long with the time.

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RezaAghaei where can i edit my code,i already tried to do this but nothing change, what change is the datetimepicker it self not the value
so can you show me please.

Comment: @RezaAghaei this all code, this code from msn site you can check the source code at the in of the post there is a link.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx
thank you

Comment: @RezaAghaei there is a small problem, when i edit the date the time shown is 12:00:00 AM , how to do it to show the current time when i edit the date

Comment: Are you editing using `DateTimePicker`? Did you show time part  in `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: Also it seems `Me.Value.ToShortDateString()` is not suitable for your requirement because it returns date part.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes im using Datetimepicker , and no the datetimepicker just show the date, see in this photo : http://store2.up-00.com/2016-09/1474036540691.png and this : http://store2.up-00.com/2016-09/1474036540772.png and this: http://store2.up-00.com/2016-09/1474036540853.png 
and after i edited date , a new row added to the gridview with the current date and time i don't want it .

Comment: Set the `Format` property of `DateTimePicker` to `Custom` and set `CustomFormat` to `yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei i did that and the picker format now when i edit the date "16/09/2016 5:51:55 PM" but when i finish editing the time is 12:00:00 AM( 
Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        Me.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")

Comment: Also correct this points of code `Me.Value.ToShortDateString()` and return the full date time format including time.

Comment: @RezaAghaei i changed the (Me.Value.ToShortDateString() to Me.Value.ToLongDateString) and nothing changed :(
 i will be grateful if you helped me in this.

Comment: No problem. I'll post the full code for you :)

Comment: ok thank you so much really :)

Comment: I posted the full code.

Comment: @RezaAghaei , i know this is a lot and i'm asking a lot i'm sorry :(
but now when i edit the date , just the date change and the time not changing to the current time. if its now " 13/09/2016 5:30:08 " if i edit the date it will be " 16/09/2016 5:30:08 ".

Comment: It's normal behavior of `DateTimePicker` control. If you don't change the time portion it remains untouched and it's reasonable. If you change the time portion yourself, you will override the changes which the user made. I'm not sure if changing the time portion is suitable or not. Also what about cases which the user wants to change the time portion? What should the control do?

Comment: @RezaAghaei is there way to make the time current when the date changed ?

Comment: Yes, there is. But you didn't say what would be the behavior when the user edits time portion? Should the edit be neglected and the current time be used?

Comment: By the way, I reverted the edit. It made the question less-readable. Your question is good enough now.

Comment: @RezaAghaei , the main things is to edit the date, but can we make it if the user edit the date the time edited also to the current time, and if he edit the time then just the time edited?
if not i think the current time when the date edited is better.
but how i can do it

Comment: You can rely on the `Date` portion and use `Time` part from `DateTime.Now`. It will be OK. Here is what you can use `Me.Value.Date.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")` Instead of `Me.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, this is perfect ,i'm so grateful thank you :)

Comment: By the way, next times in such cases it's better to ask a new question because the requirement is completely different. It's better to have an answer for such question instead of a hidden answer in comments :) Also the chance of getting answer will be more because all users see your question. But it's OK for now :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei  what do you mean about the current date or for the new code i posted ? If you mean the current time i can make a new question for it , but if you mean the new post I put it , thats for others so they can se how i did it , thank you

Comment: In my previous comment I'm talking about new requirement: *Getting the time portion from DateTime.Now in DateTimePicker Column*.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Do you want me to make new question or i can flag the comment

Comment: No, it's OK. I said that for next times :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a date and time in custom format, you should assign format to [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format(v=vs.110).aspx) property of [`DefaultCellStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx). The `CustomFormat` property of `DateTimePicker` is useful for editing format but for displaying data in cell you should use `column.DefaultCellStyle.Format`.

For example to show date and time like `2016/09/15 10:31:04 PM` you should use `yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt` as format.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now)
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now)
    Dim column = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"
    column.DataPropertyName = "Date"
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(column)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

For more information about custom date formats see:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

**DataGridView DateTimePicker Column**

Here is the full source code of date time picker column with some fixes. The source has been taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and I just made some small changes and a small fix.  The changes has been made to support `Time` and long format. Also the fix has been done to prevent exception when the cell value is `DBNull.Value`:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class CalendarColumn
    Inherits DataGridViewColumn

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(New CalendarCell())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Property CellTemplate() As DataGridViewCell
        Get
            Return MyBase.CellTemplate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridViewCell)

            ' Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            If (value IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _
                Not value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(GetType(CalendarCell)) _
                Then
                Throw New InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell")
            End If
            MyBase.CellTemplate = value

        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class CalendarCell
    Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

    Public Sub New()
        ' Use the short date format.
        Me.Style.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub InitializeEditingControl(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
        ByVal initialFormattedValue As Object, _
        ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As DataGridViewCellStyle)

        ' Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        MyBase.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, _
            dataGridViewCellStyle)

        Dim ctl As CalendarEditingControl = _
            CType(DataGridView.EditingControl, CalendarEditingControl)

        ' Use the default row value when Value property is null.
        If (Me.Value Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Me.Value)) Then
            ctl.Value = CType(Me.DefaultNewRowValue, DateTime)
        Else
            ctl.Value = CType(Me.Value, DateTime)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType() As Type
        Get
            ' Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses.
            Return GetType(CalendarEditingControl)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ValueType() As Type
        Get
            ' Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
            Return GetType(DateTime)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DefaultNewRowValue() As Object
        Get
            ' Use the current date and time as the default value.
            Return DateTime.Now
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Class CalendarEditingControl
    Inherits DateTimePicker
    Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl

    Private dataGridViewControl As DataGridView
    Private valueIsChanged As Boolean = False
    Private rowIndexNum As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        Me.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt"
    End Sub

    Public Property EditingControlFormattedValue() As Object _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue

        Get
            Return Me.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            Try
                ' This will throw an exception of the string is 
                ' null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                Me.Value = DateTime.Parse(CStr(value))
            Catch
                ' In the case of an exception, just use the default
                ' value so we're not left with a null value.
                Me.Value = DateTime.Now
            End Try
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function GetEditingControlFormattedValue(ByVal context _
        As DataGridViewDataErrorContexts) As Object _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue

        Return Me.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt")

    End Function

    Public Sub ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(ByVal dataGridViewCellStyle As  _
        DataGridViewCellStyle) _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl

        Me.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font
        Me.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor
        Me.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor

    End Sub

    Public Property EditingControlRowIndex() As Integer _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex

        Get
            Return rowIndexNum
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            rowIndexNum = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(ByVal key As Keys, _
        ByVal dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey

        ' Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
        Select Case key And Keys.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left, Keys.Up, Keys.Down, Keys.Right, _
                Keys.Home, Keys.End, Keys.PageDown, Keys.PageUp

                Return True

            Case Else
                Return Not dataGridViewWantsInputKey
        End Select

    End Function

    Public Sub PrepareEditingControlForEdit(ByVal selectAll As Boolean) _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit

        ' No preparation needs to be done.

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange() _
        As Boolean Implements _
        IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange

        Get
            Return False
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlDataGridView() As DataGridView _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView

        Get
            Return dataGridViewControl
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataGridView)
            dataGridViewControl = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public Property EditingControlValueChanged() As Boolean _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged

        Get
            Return valueIsChanged
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            valueIsChanged = value
        End Set

    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property EditingControlCursor() As Cursor _
        Implements IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor

        Get
            Return MyBase.Cursor
        End Get

    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(ByVal eventargs As EventArgs)

        ' Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        valueIsChanged = True
        Me.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(True)
        MyBase.OnValueChanged(eventargs)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And here is the test code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now)
    dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now)
    Dim column = New CalendarColumn()
    column.DataPropertyName = "Date"
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(column)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: there is a small problem, when i edit the date the time shown is 12:00:00 AM , how to do it to show the current time when i edit the date.