# Bound DataGridView not updating to display information + sorting issues

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a bound DataGridView1 and several bound TextBoxes and DateTimePickers.

Everything is working well, except when I try to accomplish these two things in conjunction:

1. Sort the DataGridView1 by a specific column (date).
2. Change that same column date based on a DateTimePicker.

The idea is that I am sorting my DataGridView1 like so (I set this in Form Load):

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(45), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

(Column 45 is just my "MyDateColumn" column)

And later on, when I change my date column like so:

```
DirectCast(MyBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Item("MyDateColumn") = MyDateTimePicker.Value.AddDays(100)
```

The DataGridView1 should automatically and immediately sort by the date.



Okay, so here's where the issue is. The sorting works - but for some reason my DataGridView refuses to reflect the date set by the DirectCast *until I select another row*. When I select another row - *then* it changes to reflect the date I just sent.

I've tried everything I could think of - and I finally found a solution:

```
Me.BindingContext(MyBindingSource).EndCurrentEdit()
```

This works great - but only if I am not using:

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(45), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

If I'm sorting my DataGridView, my binding seems to just...stop working after I .EndCurrentEdit. If I comment out that ListSortDirection.Ascending line, then it works great!

I tried to use DataGridView1.Refresh() in lieu of .EndCurrentEdit(), but it is exceptionally slow - I would rather avoid using that altogether.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: [DataGridView DateTimePicker Column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39517494/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the BindingSource data source can be sorted, use the [BindingSource.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.sort) property instead of sorting the control (your DataGridView). `columnName` is the name of the Column used for sorting (you can specify more than one Column):

```
myBindingSource.Sort = $"{columnName} ASC"
```

Then, when the User sets the `DateTimePicker.Value`, update the Cell value, corresponding to `DateTime` Column of the current Row, using the `ValueChanged` event:

**Method 1: Bound DateTimePicker**

In the `DateTimePicker.ValueChanged`, the [BindingSource.EndEdit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit) method is called, to apply immediately the new value to the data source.

<sub>**Note 1**: for this method to work as expected, the BindingSource data source must be a DataTable or another container that implements the [IEditableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject) interface.</sub>

```
DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(
    New Binding("Value", myBindingSource, "MyDateTimeColumn", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))

'(...)

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    myBindingSource.EndEdit()
End Sub
```

<sub>**Note 2**: the DateTimePicker doesn't support a `null`/`DbNull` value. If the DataSouce may contain `DBNull` values, it may become *erratic*. You'll probably need to create a custom control from it, to manage its behavior.  Otherwise, see Method 2</sub>

**Method 2: UnBound DateTimePicker**

The `userSetValue` field is used when setting the DateTimePicker value in code, to prevent the procedure in the `ValueChanged` event to update the DateTime Columns's Value. This way, the event will only update the Column when a User changes the date manually.

```
Private columnName As String = String.Empty
Private userSetValue As Boolean = True

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    If (Not userSetValue) Then Return
    If (DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing) OrElse
        (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells($"{columnName}").ValueType IsNot GetType(Date)) Then Return

    'DataGridView1.SuspendLayout()
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells($"{columnName}").Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
    myBindingSource.EndEdit()
    'DataGridView1.ResumeLayout(False)
End Sub
```

► Test both methods with and without `SuspendLayout()` / `ResumeLayout()`.

The `RowPostPaint` event (for example) can be used to update the `DateTimePicker.Value` the associated Columns' value:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint
    userSetValue = False
    Dim currentValue = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("MyDateTimeColumn").Value
    If currentValue Is Nothing OrElse currentValue Is DBNull.Value Then currentValue = Date.Now
    DateTimePicker1.Value = DirectCast(currentValue, Date)
    userSetValue = True
End Sub
```

Using any of the two methods, this is the result:

[image: DataGridView bound DateTimePicker]

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DGV shows edited value after cell validation and this seems to be an issue around DGV.
In order to do that (considered as workaround) you can simulate/force by yourself your grid validation (calling the method below) after you have setted the value on your cell:

```
Private Sub SimulateDGVValidation()

    Try

        Dim currentCell As DataGridViewCell = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell

        If (currentCell) IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim c As Integer = IIf(currentCell.ColumnIndex > 1, currentCell.ColumnIndex - 1, 1)
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1(c, currentCell.RowIndex)
        Else
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1(0, 0)
        End If


        Application.DoEvents()

        'Return in the initial cell 
        If (currentCell) IsNot Nothing Then
            Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = currentCell
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey - this actually works - but like DataGridView1.Refresh, is extremely slow.

Comment: Before you call this try adding on top of this method DataGridView1.SuspendLayout() and on end DataGridView1.ResumeLayout()

Comment: Hey - just tried this. I get a binding issue now where it seems like my DGV rows are being overwritten by a previously selected row.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's going in overpainting. I'm thinking on

Comment: It IS much faster with the Suspend and Resume Layout though. So I think we are on the right track!

Comment: At the moment the best solution to avoid slow rendering I have is: you need to implement on your grid a virtual mode approach. Using a dictionary behind (datasource -> dictionary (of Something) -> Datagridview). Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control