# Moving Rows up and down in a sorted DataTable set as the DataSource of a DataGridView does not update the View

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, datagridview, dataview

I've looked online and I've seen a lot of different posts of similar stuff.  My code moves the rows correctly. 
This is what happens: I press either the UP or Down Buttons, the selected rows moves accordingly.
If I click on the Row that I just moved and I try to move it back, it moves it in the DataTable's DefaultView sort order but the position change is NOT reflected in the DataGridView.

If I select a Row I've never moved, it will move it and the DataGridView will reflect it, but once again if I choose that same row and try to move it back, this change is not reflected in the View, but the DataTable is updated.

I've tried to `ResetBindings`, `DataGridView.Refresh`, reset the DataSource: none of this works.

Anyone know why this happens and how i can fix it so it reflects the changes every time?

```
 Private Sub UpBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpBtn.Click
    MoveUpDataRow(StepDGV.CurrentRow.Index)
End Sub

Private Sub MoveUpDataRow(RowIndex As Integer)
    Dim OriginalStepNumber As Integer
    Dim dv As DataView = StepsData.DefaultView

    OriginalStepNumber = CInt(StepDGV.Rows(RowIndex).Cells("StepIDLS").Value)

    If RowIndex = 0 Then
        'dv(RowIndex - 1)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber + 1
        'dv(RowIndex)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber - 1
        exit Sub
    Else

        dv(RowIndex - 1).BeginEdit()
        dv(RowIndex - 1)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber
        'dv(RowIndex)("StepIDLS") = RowIndex-1
        dv(RowIndex - 1).EndEdit()

        dv(RowIndex).BeginEdit()
        dv(RowIndex)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber - 1
        'dv(RowIndex)("StepIDLS") = RowIndex-1
        dv(RowIndex).EndEdit()

    End If
    dv.Sort = "StepIDLS ASC"
  '  StepDGV.Rows(RowIndex).Selected = true
    'StepDGV.DataSource = StepsData
    'StepDGV.Refresh()
    StepDGV.ResetBindings()
    StepDGV.Refresh()

End Sub


Private Sub downBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles downBtn.Click
    MoveDownDataRow(StepDGV.CurrentRow.Index)
End Sub

Private Sub MoveDownDataRow(RowIndex As Integer)
    Dim OriginalStepNumber As Integer
    Dim dv As DataView = StepsData.DefaultView

    OriginalStepNumber = CInt(StepDGV.Rows(RowIndex).Cells("StepIDLS").Value)

    If RowIndex = dv.Count - 1 Then
        exit Sub
    Else

        dv(RowIndex + 1).BeginEdit()
        dv(RowIndex + 1)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber
        dv(RowIndex + 1).EndEdit()

        dv(RowIndex).BeginEdit()
        dv(RowIndex)("StepIDLS") = OriginalStepNumber + 1
        dv(RowIndex).EndEdit()

    End If
    dv.Sort = "StepIDLS ASC"
  '  StepDGV.Rows(RowIndex).Selected = true
    'StepDGV.Refresh()
    'StepDGV.DataSource = StepsData
    'StepDGV.Refresh()
    StepDGV.ResetBindings()
    StepDGV.Refresh()

End Sub[![screenshot of datagridview for visual aid when going through code][1]][1]
```

Comment: What is StepDGV? Is it the DataTable or the DataGridView?

Comment: that is the DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a sorted DataView, setting two consecutive values using the same Index reference, may (will) have undefined results, even more if you move in two different *directions*.

**Method 1:**

It's simpler (and functional) to get the reference of both DataRows from the current DataView and then change the value of a Column using the DataRow reference: even if the DataRow position in the sorted DataView changes, the DataRow reference is the same.

You don't need to BeginEdit/EndEdit a Cell value, these changes are propagated automatically.

► Here, I'm using the same `Button.Click` handler for both Buttons and determine the direction based on the Button name (it could be anything else that fits).

► This line: `Dim dView = DirectCast(StepDGV.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView` is not necessary if you have stored a DataTable object (as it looks like).
If that's the case, of course use the DataTable reference you already have.

► It's assumed you have set **`StepsData.DefaultView.Sort = "StepIDLS ASC"`** before this point.

```
Private Sub btnMoveRowUpDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpBtn.Click, downBtn.Click
    If StepDGV.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then Return

    Dim moveUp As Boolean = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name.Equals("UpBtn")

    Dim currentRow As Integer = StepDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim dView = DirectCast(StepDGV.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView
    Dim rowCurrent = dView(currentRow).Row
    Dim colCurrentValue As Integer = CType(rowCurrent("StepIDLS"), Integer)

    If moveUp Then
        If currentRow = 0 Then Return

        Dim rowPrevious = dView(currentRow - 1).Row
        Dim colPreviousValue As Integer = CType(rowPrevious("StepIDLS"), Integer)
        rowCurrent("StepIDLS") = colPreviousValue
        rowPrevious("StepIDLS") = colCurrentValue
    Else
        If currentRow = StepDGV.NewRowIndex - 1 Then Return

        Dim rowNext = dView(currentRow + 1).Row
        Dim colNextValue As Integer = CType(rowNext("StepIDLS"), Integer)
        rowCurrent("StepIDLS") = colNextValue
        rowNext("StepIDLS") = colCurrentValue
    End If
End Sub
```

**Method 2:**

You can do something similar setting the DataGridView Cells values.
In this case, you do need to call [DataGridView.EndEdit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.endedit) to notify the change, so it occurs immediately. Otherwise, the value change would be propagated after the focus leaves the [`CurrentCell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell).

The notes here: [Bound DataGridView not updating to display information + sorting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006605/7444103) may also be useful in a similar condition (when you have to directly set DataGridView Cells).

You can also notice that setting a DataRow Colums value also changes the DataGridView [`CurrentRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow) (not just the `CurrentCell`), while setting the Value of a Cell in a DataGridView, doesn't cause the `CurrentRow` to change, so you have to do it yourself, setting:

```
[DataGridView].CurrentCell = [DataGridView].Rows(currentRow + 1).Cells(currentColumn)
```

```
Private Sub btnMoveRowUpDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpBtn.Click, downBtn.Click
    If StepDGV.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then Return

    Dim moveUp As Boolean = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name.Equals("UpBtn")

    Dim currentRow As Integer = StepDGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim currentColumn As Integer = StepDGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim currentCellValue As Integer = CType(StepDGV("StepIDLS", currentRow).Value, Integer)

    If moveUp Then
        If currentRow = 0 Then Return 
        Dim previousCellValue As Integer = CType(StepDGV("StepIDLS", currentRow - 1).Value, Integer)

        StepDGV.Rows(currentRow).Cells("StepIDLS").Value = previousCellValue
        StepDGV.EndEdit()
        StepDGV.Rows(currentRow - 1).Cells("StepIDLS").Value = currentCellValue
        StepDGV.EndEdit()
        StepDGV.CurrentCell = StepDGV.Rows(currentRow - 1).Cells(currentColumn)
    Else
        If currentRow = StepDGV.NewRowIndex - 1 Then Return 
        Dim nextCellValue As Integer = CType(StepDGV("StepIDLS", currentRow + 1).Value, Integer)

        StepDGV.Rows(currentRow).Cells("StepIDLS").Value = nextCellValue
        StepDGV.EndEdit()
        StepDGV.Rows(currentRow + 1).Cells("StepIDLS").Value = currentCellValue
        StepDGV.EndEdit()
        StepDGV.CurrentCell = StepDGV.Rows(currentRow + 1).Cells(currentColumn)
    End If
End Sub
```