# The value of the DatagridView's cell appears to change, but it does not

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, datasource

I have a DatagridView whose DataSource is a DataTable.
When I change a cell's value at runtime, it appears to be changing well.

However, if I try to assign a value from the DataGridView to a variable by clicking on a row in the DatagridView, the variable gets the original (DataTable) value, not the cell's value.

`copy = DataGridView2.Item(7, i).Value`

The ReadOnly property of the cells column is false.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Call `Validate()` or `EndEdit()` (depending on the context), See, e.g., [Bound DataGridView not updating to display information + sorting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006605/7444103)

Comment: If the grid uses a data source, then technically the `DataSource` should get updated if a cell value is changed. Where are you calling `copy = DataGridView2.Item(7, i).Value` … ? … And can you provide a [mre] that reproduces what you describe.

Comment: @Jimi I've modified my code to your advice. I have a `BindigSource` whose `DataSource` is the `DataTable`. The `DataSource` of my `DataGridView` is now the `BindingSource`. The `CellValueChanged` event calls the `EndEdit()` method. Unfortunately, the old value is still taken by the variable. What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to post your code. All the code needed to reproduce the behavior you're describing. E.g., *the old value is still taken by the variable*: when an where are you reading this value? -- Note that calling `EndEdit()` in `CellValueChanged` should be done with caution (can have *side effects*); see the notes there. It can be used when you want specific values to be applied immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the help but in the meantime I figured out a working solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with this method:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellEndEdit
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index
    DataGridView2.DataSource.Rows(i)("copy") = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value        
End Sub
```

This way, the variable will take on the correct value after I overwrite the value of the cell in the DatagridView.

Comment: We are glad you got this working, however, there is one thing in your answer that may result in the code grabbing the wrong cell. Your answer “assumes” that the grid and its `DataSource` are in a one-to-one relationship… i.e.… row 1 in the grid is row 1 in the data source. This may not always be the case, example if the grid is sorted or filtered. You may want to look at the grid row’s `DataBoundItem` property.

Comment: If every time a cell in the grid ends its edit, the code executes the “extra” steps to put the value from the grid cell into the same cell in the `DataTable/Source`... THEN… why bother with the `DataTable`? Just get the data from the grid! I am just saying that the code is doing something that “SHOULD” be done for you automatically and you “SHOULD” be asking why it is not.